# bootstrap collapse menu appearing above the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I making a website with bootstrap. I have made this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Krishna Driver Services</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webstyle.css">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">      

      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>

          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="images\logo.png">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

& this css code

```
.navbar-default{
    min-height:160px;   
}
```

My collapse menu is appearing just above the logo. I think it's occurring due to change of navbar width.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

It has been made clear to me in the comments that I missed the point of the question, so here's the real answer:

You have to make sure, that not only the navbar, but also the navbar-header change height. The obvious way to do that is to change your CSS to

```
.navbar-default, .navbar-default .navbar-header{
  min-height:160px;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cr2frn1p/6/

I'm sure there are other, more elegant solutions and I'm sure I've used one of them in a project not so long ago, but I currently have no time to search for it. If you're interested, I can include it here tomorrow.

**ORIGINAL POST**

Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/cr2frn1p/

Doing some guesswork here: You might be referring to the fact, that the top edge of the logo and the button are not perfectly aligned. That's because .navbar-brand has a padding of 15px while .navbar-toggle has a margin of 8px, just add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't load a version of jQuery, nor does it include the .js library for Bootstrap. As such it's not fully functioning, and this answer doesn't address the problem the asker is having. Load it up correctly and you'll see what they're talking about.

Comment: Tested it with jquery-1.11: http://jsfiddle.net/cr2frn1p/4/ and jquery-2.1: http://jsfiddle.net/cr2frn1p/5/ Still can't find anything that's wrong

Comment: Collapse the result view so it triggers the mobile toggle button, then click the button....

Comment: Now I see, typical case of me not seeing the obvious. Thanks for pointing it out to me, update of my answer with a fix is coming right up.